# Azure web app application insights query for Operation/Dependency time, Duration and count over a period

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-log-analytics

I am looking for azure web insights query for Operation/Dependency name, time(average), duration and count over a period (say last one week)

Comment: What have you [tried so far](https://docs.loganalytics.io/docs/Learn/Getting-Started/Getting-started-with-queries)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dependencies
 | where timestamp > startofweek(now()) 
 | summarize count() by name 
 |order by name asc 
 | join kind= inner (
 dependencies
 | where timestamp > startofweek(now()) 
 | summarize avg(duration) by name
 |order by name    
 ) on name
```